# Should I write "taunt" or "taunts" in the following sentence?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

> I cupped my ears so I wouldn’t be able to hear my classmates' taunt(s)
>   and scorn.

What's the correct option, "taunt" or "taunts", and why?

Comment: Taunt is countable, I'd use "taunts "in your sentence: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/taunt

Comment: 'I like bacon and eggs' shows that non-count and count usages may be coordinated. 'Taunts' doesn't mean that there are necessarily essentially different forms; _different utterances made by **children**_ licenses the plural verb-form.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth funny, when *usually* one has more individual bacon units than egg units... Is 'bacon' non-count here?

Comment: You need to read the previous articles on and otherwise addressing countness. 'Cattle' is non-count because 'two / 17 / 56 cattle' is ungrammatical, in spite of the fact that the cows etc can be counted. In 'a muted light flooded the clearing', 'light' is the non-count usage because 'two / 53 ... muted lights' is impossible here. Non-count, in spite of the indefinite article. 'Bacon' is only used as a count noun when referring to a joint. {[M-W, sense 1a](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bacon): << Definition of bacon
1a :  a side of a pig cured and smoked  >>} ...

Comment: Otherwise it's 'rashers of bacon'. Check on etic countability vs countness vs verb agreement.

Comment: @alex - You've misunderstood idiomatic [to cup one's ears](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/to-cup-ones-ears.2261424/). Per that link, it means *place your hands in a cup shape behind your ears [so that] you can hear **more*** (not ***less***). If you want to ***shut the noise out***, you might ***cover your ears***.

Comment: (1) Ditto.  “Bacon” is non-count, like “pork” (and “beef”).  “Pork and beans” is a near-perfect parallel to “bacon and eggs”.  (2) The interesting thing is that these phrases are *singular* : “bacon and eggs is the most popular item on the menu”. (3) See also: “I have 43 chickens.  Tonight I will have [some] chicken for dinner; then I will have 42 chickens.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming they're producing several taunts, and not saying a single taunt, I would expect the plural.

Scorn is a feeling not distinguishable from other scorning, so would be just the general feeling of scorn.

Edit: Although from the sentence, it sounds like the subject is hearing scorn, which is questionable.

Comment: And since classmate***s*** is plural, one could assume that there will be more than one taunt.

Comment: @marcellothearcane Not sure, if the taunting was a regular occurrence its possible they've developed a chant through the bonding-via-ostracization process. A chant, although repetitive, would be a single taunt. Realistically, you'd likely never describe it that way. Or, possibly, it's a SciFi piece where the students have a hive mind and taunt in unison and only once for efficiency's sake.

Answer (score 0):

First person: Taunt.
Example: **I** taunt, **we** taunt.

Second person: Taunt.
Example: **You** taunt, **ye** taunt.

Third person (singular): Taunts.
Example: **He** taunts, **she** taunts, **it** taunts.

Third person (plural, subjective / objective): Taunt.
Example: **They** taunt, taunt **them**. (verb) **them** taunt.

Third person (plural, verb or noun): Taunt(s).
Example: **Their** taunt or their **taunts**.

Now, with sentence you gave us, we just need to separate it into parts to find our nouns:
**"I cupped my ears so I wouldn’t be able to hear my classmates' taunt(s) and scorn."**
The first subject (noun) is "I" and the additional one is "Classmates". So, if you replace the additional noun for a pronoun, you'll get:
**"I cupped my ears so I wouldn’t be able to hear them taunt(s) and scorn."**

Using the examples from the "Third person, plural" category, we can say that your sentence should be written as the following:
**"I cupped my ears so I wouldn’t be able to hear my classmates taunt and scorn."**

[EDIT]
Unless you're wanting to use **their**, in which case, you should write:
**"I cupped my ears so I wouldn’t be able to hear their taunts and scorn."** or **"I cupped my ears so I wouldn’t be able to hear my classmates' taunts and scorn."**

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they#Contemporary_usage (Inflected forms and derivative pronouns)

Comment: "taunt(s)" in the original poster's sentence is a noun, not a verb. It uses *my classmates'* with an apostrophe, which would be replaced by a genitive pronoun like "their", not by an accusative pronoun like "them". And even in a sentence like "I cupped my ears so I wouldn’t be able to hear them taunt me", the word "taunt" would be an infinitive, which is invariant for number: we would also say "I cupped my ears so I wouldn’t be able to hear him taunt me". It would be incorrect to write something like ""I cupped my ears so I wouldn’t be able to hear him taunts me".